# MySQL Connector Multiple Servers different port

Tags: .net, mysql, port, mysql-connector, multiple-databases

I have an app that will be supported by two MySQL servers. They reside on 2 different machine on different network and on different ports.

i found in [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) the following connection string for multiple servers

```
Server =serverAddress1 &amp; serverAddress2 &amp; etc..; Database =myDataBase; Uid =myUsername; Pwd =myPassword;
```

But how can i specify the port for each server?

Comment: where did you find this connectionstring? in general the port follows the ip address or host name like this: hostNameServerOne:12345

Comment: in my post i have hyperlinked the website where i found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That connection string is for connecting to replicated servers, it'll just chose one of them - does it matter which server you use, in your application ?

Anyway - you can't specify different port that way, so you will have to handle this yourself in your application logic, backed by 2 distinct connection strings.